One dimensional quadratic discriminant analysis in matlab
My nightmares with discriminant analysis continue...
Trying to plot the "one dimensional" quadratic discriminant analysis, where the discriminant is only being decided on by the x-axis. It works fine for linear (as shown in the code sample) but I can't get the quadratic (aka curved) boundaries to plot correctly. I've tried a few things (all in the code sample) to no avail.
I think the issue is with what I'm passing to the implicit function, when I had problems with the 3D case this was the solution, but I just don't understand how to fix it myself.
I have noticed that Qxx(1,2) = -1*Qxx(2,1), but not sure how that contributes to the issue.
clear
clc
close all

%----------------------------
x1 = 1:0.01:3;
r = -1 + (1+1)*rand(1,201);
x1 = x1 + r;

y1 = 1:0.01:3;
r = -1 + (1+1)*rand(1,201);
y1 = y1 + r;

x1 = x1';
y1 = y1';

label1 = ones(length(y1),1);

Tclust1 = [label1,x1,y1];
%----------------------------
x2 = 7:0.01:9;
r = -1 + (1+1)*rand(1,201);
x2 = x2 + r;

y2 = 10:0.01:12;
r = -1 + (1+1)*rand(1,201);
y2 = y2 + r;

x2 = x2';
y2 = y2';

label2 = 2.*ones(length(y2),1);

Tclust2 = [label2,x2,y2];

%----------------------------
x3 = 15:0.01:17;
r = -1 + (1+1)*rand(1,201);
x3 = x3 + r;

y3 = 13:0.01:15;
r = -1 + (1+1)*rand(1,201);
y3 = y3 + r;

x3 = x3';
y3 = y3';

label3 = 3.*ones(length(y3),1);

Tclust3 = [label3,x3,y3];

%----------------------------
T = [Tclust1;Tclust2;Tclust3];

data = T(:,2:3);
labels = T(:,1);

%LOOCV
n = length(labels);
hpartition = cvpartition(n,'leaveout');

% figure()
output = zeros(n,3);

for qq = 1:n
    %training data
idx_Train = training(hpartition,qq);
data_Train = data(idx_Train,1:2);
labels_Train = labels(idx_Train);

    %test data
idx_Test = test(hpartition,qq);
data_Test = data(idx_Test,1:2);
labels_Test = labels(idx_Test);

%train the model on the training data
Mdlquad = fitcdiscr(data_Train,labels_Train,'Discrimtype','quadratic');

%apply to the testing data
pred_lbl = predict(Mdlquad,data_Test);

(qq/n)*100
end

iscorrect=output(:,1)==output(:,2);
accuracy_full = (sum(iscorrect)/length(iscorrect))*100;

%get coeffs
K12 = Mdlquad.Coeffs(1,2).Const;
L12 = Mdlquad.Coeffs(1,2).Linear;
Q12 = Mdlquad.Coeffs(1,2).Quadratic;
            
K23 = Mdlquad.Coeffs(2,3).Const;
L23 = Mdlquad.Coeffs(2,3).Linear;
Q23 = Mdlquad.Coeffs(2,3).Quadratic;

K13 = Mdlquad.Coeffs(1,3).Const;
L13 = Mdlquad.Coeffs(1,3).Linear;
Q13 = Mdlquad.Coeffs(1,3).Quadratic;
            
%plot data with boundaries -----------------------------------------------
data = T(:,2:3);
labels = T(:,1);
xmin = min(T(:,2));
xmax = max(T(:,2));
ymin = min(T(:,3));
ymax = max(T(:,3));

%plot linear...
figure()
scatter(x1,y1,'g')
hold on
scatter(x2,y2,'b')
scatter(x3,y3,'r')

title('Linear = correct')
xlabel('variable')
ylabel('control')
%legend('Data 1','Data 2','Data 3','Boundary 1 -> 2','Boundary 2 -> 3','Boundary 1 -> 3','location','eastoutside') 

            %group 1 and group 2
            f12 = @(x1,x2) K12 + L12(1)*x1 + L12(2)*x1;
            h2 = fimplicit(f12,[xmin xmax ymin ymax],'--g');

            %group 2 and group 3
            f23 = @(x1) K23 + L23(1)*x1+ L23(2)*x1;
            h3 = fimplicit(f23,[xmin xmax ymin ymax],'--r');

            %group 1 and group 3
            f13 = @(x1) K13 + L13(1)*x1+ L13(2)*x1;
            h4 = fimplicit(f13,[xmin xmax ymin ymax],'--b');

%plot quadratic...
figure()
scatter(x1,y1,'g')
hold on
scatter(x2,y2,'b')
scatter(x3,y3,'r')

title('Quadratic = Problematic')
xlabel('variable')
ylabel('control')
%legend('Data 1','Data 2','Data 3','Boundary 1 -> 2','Boundary 2 -> 3','Boundary 1 -> 3','location','eastoutside') 

%group 1 and group 2
            
            f12 = @(x1) K12 + Q12(1)*x1.^2 + Q12(2)*x1.^2 + Q12(3)*x1.^2+ Q12(4)*x1.^2;
            h2 = fimplicit(f12,[xmin xmax ymin ymax],'--g');

            %group 2 and group 3
            f23 = @(x1) K23 + Q23(1)*x1.^2 + Q23(2)*x1.^2 + Q23(4)*x1.^2;
            h3 = fimplicit(f23,[xmin xmax ymin ymax],'--r');

            %group 1 and group 3
            f13 = @(x1) K13 + Q13(1)*x1.^2 + (Q13(2)+Q13(3))*x1.^2 + Q13(4)*x1.^2;
            h4 = fimplicit(f13,[xmin xmax ymin ymax],'--b');


Previous issue with 3d discriminant and solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79271633/plotting-outputs-of-3d-quadratic-discriminant-analysis-in-matlab/79284721?noredirect=1#comment139816256_79284721

“I can't get the quadratic (aka curved) boundaries to plot correctly.” Do you get an error message? or a boundary that is not what you expect? Is the plotting bad or is the discriminant itself bad? It would be much easier on us if you could remove things that are not relevant to the question from your code, see [mre]. There’s a lot there and it’s hard to know what your problem might be.

Hi Cris, this is a minimum reproducible example, which generates the test data, runs the analysis, then plots the outputs, including the linear discriminant for reference.  Whilst there's no error code, the issue is clear, the boundaries between the groups just aren't present on figure 2. So, something is wrong with how I'm plotting figure 2, at the very end of the code sample. Could be as simple as "evaluating the coeffs incorrectly", which was the issue with the 3d question I posted, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to correct it for this.

For clarity, I think the issue with the code is L147 and onwards.
'f12 = @(x1)...'
On fig2, the boundaries between the groups just aren't there.

Well, did you look at the documentation? https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/classificationdiscriminant.html#bs1qffl-1_sep_shared-Coeffs : "The equation of the boundary between class i and class j is Const + Linear * x + x' * Quadratic * x = 0, where x is a column vector of length p." That doesn't look anywhere near what you're doing.

Yes, I even looked at the worked examples: https://au.mathworks.com/help/stats/create-and-visualize-discriminant-analysis-classifier.html
f = @(x1,x2) K + L(1)*x1 + L(2)*x2 + Q(1,1)*x1.^2 + (Q(1,2)+Q(2,1))*x1.*x2 + Q(2,2)*x2.^2; h2 = fimplicit(f,[.9 7.1 0 2.5]); h2.Color = 'r'; h2.LineWidth = 2; h2.DisplayName = 'Boundary between Versicolor & Virginica';
However this example is using x1 and x2, where as I only want to use x1.

I don’t understand “I only want to use x1”. You are defining a function f(x,y). You need to use both coordinates if you want to draw anything other than a vertical line. Also, your code in the question is ignoring the linear part, so you didn’t copy the example well enough.

@CrisLuengo I'm not sure how to explain without sounding condescending and I believe you are causing an xy problem, please re-read the question carefully.
In the example they have 2 variables, x1 and x2. I want to use only 1 variable not 2... so just x1, with y1 being the control variable, similar to fig 1 in my code.
You state "You need to use both co-ords.. if you want to draw anything other than a vertical line" I'm afraid y = x^2 begs to differ.
I am ignoring the linear because I want quadratic discriminant analysis. You may be correct that this is wrong... but what is right?

Ok, let me rephrase that. You are calling fimplicit. The docs say “fimplicit(f) plots the implicit function defined by f(x,y) = 0.”  https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fimplicit.html  Thus, you need to give it a function of x and y, and you need to use both variables if you don’t want to draw a vertical line. If you want to draw y=x^2, you pass it f(x,y)=x^2-y. If you have a function in the form f(x)=x^2, then you need to use a different function to plot it. Try for example fplot.  https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fplot.html

But a 2D discriminant function cannot, in general, be written in the form f(x), you need to use fimplicit with f(x,y).
